# How to fix journalctl error logs in Arch Linux

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I'm new to Arch Linux,i installed it a month ago, so sorry if this is a stupid question.
Today when I booted my computer I saw some errors, so I checked journalctl and a lot of hardware errors and some other stuff came up.

```
sudo journalctl -p 3 -xb

-- Journal begins at Sun 2021-05-23 19:57:18 IST, ends at Sat 2021-05-29 09:22:05 IST. --
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210105/psargs-330)
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU1._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210105/psparse-529)
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210105/psargs-330)
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU2._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210105/psparse-529)
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210105/psargs-330)
May 28 08:54:16 vinayks-pc kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU3._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210105/psparse-529)
May 28 08:54:22 vinayks-pc kernel: kfd kfd: TOPAZ  not supported in kfd
May 28 08:54:44 vinayks-pc gdm-password][825]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
May 28 08:54:50 vinayks-pc pulseaudio[970]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
May 28 10:58:04 vinayks-pc systemd-coredump[8529]: [] Process 8496 (nautilus) of user 0 dumped core.
```

Can anyone please tell me what should I do to fix these?

Comment: have you tried to search for each error in each line?

Comment: Is there any command for getting error for each line.

Comment: @Shōgun8 means that you should copy the text and paste it into a search engine. Example: https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22ACPI+BIOS+Error+(bug):+Could+not+resolve+symbol%22.

Comment: Your PC ran for 2+ hours - did anything significant fail to run?

Comment: No.its seems running normal  @Jeremy Boden.

Comment: @berndbausch  i tried searching on google but i can't find any fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After Switched My Kernel to `linux-lts`**

```
$ pacman -S linux-lts

$ pacman -R linux

$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts
    Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
    Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
    done

$ uname -a 
  Linux vinayks-pc 5.10.41-1-lts #1 SMP Fri, 28 May 2021 15:03:28 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

the error and warning messages are finally gone.

```
$ journalctl -p 3 -xb
-- Journal begins at Sat 2021-05-29 17:53:56 IST, ends at Sun 2021-05-30 11:10:>
May 30 10:57:36 vinayks-pc kernel: platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resour>
May 30 10:57:36 vinayks-pc kernel: acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation f>
May 30 10:57:41 vinayks-pc kernel: kfd kfd: TOPAZ  not supported in kfd
May 30 10:58:18 vinayks-pc gdm-password][794]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon>
May 30 10:58:22 vinayks-pc pulseaudio[894]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.fre>
lines 1-6/6 (END)
```